# How can I instantly move the cursor to the end of a long document in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ui, text-editor

I edit Markdown documents on iPhone 7 sometimes. Some of the documents I want to work with are pretty long — 15,000 words or more.

When I open a document to work on it (for example in the Byword or Ulysses apps, or even just a really long email), usually I want to append new text to the **end** of the document.

**Scrolling** to the end of a 15k-word file by swiping repeatedly takes a really long time.

Is there some functional equivalent of an "end" button in iOS?

---

UPDATE

Hm. We seem to be getting hung up on the idea of an "end button." Maybe I shouldn't have used that analogy.

By **"equivalent to"** I mean **any** UI control, whether it's a gesture or a hidden control or **anything at all** that will take you directly to the end of a file. It doesn't have to be a button.

To be clear, what I'm asking is, **is there *some* way, *any* way, to go instantly to the end of a file?**

Comment: Is your question about an End button in Byword/Ulysses or in iOS in general?

Comment: I'm not aware of a scroll to end gesture, but I do know that any Bluetooth keyboard with an End key equivalent will work just the same in iOS as it does in macOS.

Comment: You can use all the same standard macOS keyboard shortcuts on iOS as well. I recommend getting a keyboard if you do lots of heavy text work on your iOS device.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. I do appreciate the advice, and I'm sure that solution would work for a lot of people. In my case, a keyboard would defeat the purpose. It's a phone. I want to do a little inconspicuous writing on in while I'm waiting for this or that. If you throw in a keyboard, it's no longer *just a phone* and now I need a backpack and some sort of stand or dock to hold the phone vertically. At that point, I might as well just bring my laptop. But I'm sure that suggestion is 100% viable for people who focus the bulk of their work on their mobile devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your updated question, the answer is no; there's not a standard, built-into iOS way to go to the end of a file.

Individual apps are able to create custom gestures or menu commands to perform that function, so it might exist in specific apps but there's no standard way that works with every app.

Answer (score 0):

My long doc is a roll up of my notes for the year so I can do a Find for something like "08-25" to jump to my entry for August 25, for example, but that of course won't work in all files.